# php echo selected folder as input to another php function

Tags: php, post

I am creating a webpage that has two components

1. A list all the folders.
2. A list all the images within each folder.

My folder structure is as follows:

directory - resources

subdirectories -> location1,location2,location3

images - in each location i have -> image1,image2,image3

The php code to list all folders and print all images works fine.  However I want the functionality where when the user selects a folder from the first php i want the images to be rendered through the second php.

**directories.php**

PHP Code to list folders  (This works fine):

```
<?php
$direc = "";
if($handle = opendir('resources/')){
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))
        {
        $direc .= '<li name="fold"><a href="#">'.$file.'</a></li>';
        $nam = $_POST['fold'];
        echo $nam;  //This is not echoing
        }
    }
 closedir($handle);
}
?>



<form method="POST"  action="images.php">
<ul>
<?php echo  $direc; ?>
</ul>   
</form>
```

**images.php**

PHP CODE to list all images:  This code also works fine

```
<div>

<?php
$files = glob("resources/location1/*.jpg");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" height = "200" width = "180" id="thumbNails"/>'."<br /><br />";
    $filname = basename($num, ".jpg");
    $filnam = substr($filname, -5);
    print $filnam."<br />";
}
?>

</div>
```

Not sure how to adapt this line in the second php:

```
$files = glob($nam/"*.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I resolved this.  The following is the code:

**directories.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="test1.php" method="get">

            <select id="dirs" name="myname">
                <option value="" selected="selected">SELECT A PROJECT</option>
                      <?php
                         $dirs = glob("/var/www/html/yourdirectory/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                            foreach($dirs as $val){
                               echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
                            }
                      ?>
                  </select>


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click">
        </form>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**subdirectories.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $var = $_GET['myname'];
    $direc = "";
    if($handle = opendir($var)){
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
     {
     if (($file != ".") && ($file != ".."))
     {
     $direc .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
     }
     }
     closedir($handle);
}
?>

<div>

     <h5>LIST OF DIRECTORIES</h5> 
      <ul>
        <form action="footer.php" method="post">
        <p name="filesel"><?php echo $direc ?></p>
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `Recursive` instead which is much easier. Try this:

**Whole Code**

```
$root = __DIR__;
$selected_folder = $_POST['fold'];

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);

$folder_paths = array($root);
$image_paths = array();
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
    if ($dir->isDir()) {
        $folder_paths[] = $path;
        if(!empty(glob($path .'/*.jpg'))){
            $image_paths[] = glob($path .'/*.jpg');
        }
    }
}

$display_images = array();
foreach($image_paths as $folders){
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        if(strpos($folder, $selected_folder) !== false){
            $display_images[] = $path;
        }
    }
}
print_r($display_images);
```

Comment: thank you....this works well and it prints the directories and files within the directory...though I need to figure out how to echo out the selected folder to display the images within the folder.

Comment: as i keep working on this...i realised that I do not have problem in getting the folder names printed or getting the image paths printed. the codes which I have does that as well....however the problem that i am facing is how to I get the two linked.  For example, when the user selects the first folder, i want to display the images in the first folder.  While your code is far superior to mine, my apologies, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: It's okay. I understand. Is this `$_POST['fold']` is the selected folder?

Comment: Yes...it is the folder selected by the user from the list of displayed folders and I want to display the images based on the selection..

Comment: @popeye I updated my answer that check the selected folder. Try it and tell me if this is okay :)

Comment: Hi...thank you.....this code too prints only the arrays for both `$image_paths` and `$folder_paths`.  The `$display_images` returns a plain `Array()`.  I am not sure if I am missing something.  Since I am new to PHP and certainly to your version of programming, finding it difficult to get the connect. The thing is I have two pages.  On one page I am listing the folders and allowing the users to click.  Based on the selection, on another page I am listing all the images hence I thought `$_POST` could be the way out.

Comment: Since I have many such layers where based on the user selection on drop downs, select options, radio buttons, the redirect or data gets rendered differently.  I am stuck with still the first step.  The irony is every option is working fine individually..but not when I try to connect them with `$_POST`.